# Visual Studio issues installing/updates/corrupted files

Tags: windows, visual-studio, updates

I have a huge problem with Visual Studio 2015 and I can not resolve it.
I need it for school and I've tried almost everything what I've found on the internet but with no results.

So, I have to install Visual Studio 2015. When I try to install it, it says that I have to install kb 2919355 update. I downloaded it from Microsoft site but it gives me the error that

```
"This update is not applicable to your computer".
```

I checked that error more carefully and I found out that I need to have installed update kb 2919442 to allow update kb 2919355 to be installed on my pc.Btw, I have a Lenovo G500, Windows 8.1 Pro N
Again, I downloaded from Microsoft the update kb 2919442 but it gives me the same error:"This update is not applicable to your computer".

I enter on every page that I found related to my problem but with no result.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/cannot-install-kb2919442-because-it-is-not/37aa4487-5304-49b2-af18-327dfe760753?tab=question&status=AllReplies&auth=1#tabs

I assumed that I have a corrupted file.I followed the steps presented on the link below, I run `sfc /scannow` and I found some corrupted files that it couldn't be resolved.The file was: CNBJ2530.PNB.So I tried to check my friends' computers for the same version as I have and to copy the good file in my computer.
My mother's computer has no issues so I copy in a USB her good file, I copied then in my computer and I did the takeown, icacls, and copy commands to overwrite my bad file with the good one.The transition was done, I restarted the computer but when I run again sfc /scannow it gave me again "Windows couldn't resolve the corrupted files that are in your pc......" and I found out that again that file CNBJ2530.PNB is corrupted.

So I didn't make something well.My corrupted file was at the address:

```
 C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prncacla.inf_amd64_95d0460bc8b6fae8\Amd64
```

So I run the commands:

```
 takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prncacla.inf_amd64_95d0460bc8b6fae8\Amd64\CNBJ2530.PNB

 icacls C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prncacla.inf_amd64_95d0460bc8b6fae8\Amd64\CNBJ2530.PNB /GRANT ADMINISTRATORS:F
```

and I have created a new folder in windows folder from c and I put there my mom's file copied from usb and I run the command:

```
copy C:\Windows\cnb\CNB_0428.GPD C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prncacla.inf_amd64_95d0460bc8b6fae8\Amd64\CNBJ2530.PNB
```

- I don't know why it has changed the name of the file in CNB_0428.GPD.

What's going on and what I didn't do well?
I have to say that I have installed my windows recently but I have installed the same windows on my mother's computer and she doesn't have corrupted files and another thing, one of my friend has installed Visual Studio and she also have the some corrupted files as I have and she could installed it.

I really don't know what to do, please if someone has encountered this problem share with me.

Comment: Have you considered creating a virtual machine and installing Visual Studio 2015 on that instead? Something like Oracle VM VirtualBox, which is free. I know this doesn't help fix your Windows problem but it will allow you to get VS installed and running.

Comment: I have to work with sql server too and with back-end part.Won't be problems if I have installed it in Virtual Box?

Comment: Is it a local copy of SQL Server? If so, you could install that on the same VM. If not, you can configure the VM to access the network.

Comment: I don't know if is a local copy or not. Thank you for your help but I think is much complicated this way. I think the only solution is to reinstall the windows again. Some weeks ago I have the Core Version and I could install VS but it wasn't a genuine version..

Comment: One more thing: I downloaded the link for VS from internet. I'm a student so I have access to dreamspark. If I downloaded from there may not be problems so it doesn't matter from where I take it?